# How to transpose data to hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, unpivot

This Is My hive table:

```
dept_id emp_cnt emp_cnt_prev_yr sales_cnt sales_cnt_prev_yr
1       10      8               10000     5000
2       15      9               20000     12000
3       12      10              30000     15000
4       6       12              40000     20000
```

I want to store data into another hive table like below:

```
dept_id metric_nm metric_val metric_val_prev-yr
1       emp_cnt   10         8
2       emp_cnt   15         9
3       emp_cnt   12         10
4       emp_cnt   6          12
1       sales_cnt 10000      5000
2       sales_cnt 20000      12000
3       sales_cnt 30000      15000
4       sales_cnt 40000      20000
```

What I tried so far:

```
 SELECT dept_id,
       metric_nm,
       Substr(metrics,1,Locate('#',metrics,1)-1) AS metric_val,
       Substr(metrics,Locate('#',metrics,1)+1)   AS metric_val_prev_yr
FROM   (
              SELECT dept_id,
                     Map('emp_cnt', Concat(emp_cnt,'#',emp_cnt_prev_yr),'sales_cnt', Concat(sales_cnt,'#',sales_cnt_prev_yr)) AS metrc
              FROM   <TABLE>) a lateral VIEW explode(metric) ext AS metric_nm,
       metrics;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try so far? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: SELECT dept_id,metric_nm, SUBSTR(metrics,1,locate('#',metrics,1)-1) as metric_val, SUBSTR(metrics,locate('#',metrics,1)+1) as metric_val_prev_yr from (select dept_id, MAP('emp_cnt', CONCAT(emp_cnt,'#',emp_cnt_prev_yr),'sales_cnt', CONCAT(sales_cnt,'#',sales_cnt_prev_yr)) as metrc from <table>) a LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(metric) ext AS metric_nm, metrics;

Answer (score 2):

Use UNION ALL to combine two metric_nm datasets into single one:

```
insert overwrite table table_name

select dept_id, 'emp_cnt' as metric_nm,  
       emp_cnt as metric_val, emp_cnt_prev_yr as metric_val_prev_yr
  from your_table

UNION ALL

select dept_id, 'sales_cnt' as metric_nm,  
       sales_cnt as metric_val, sales_cnt_prev_yr as metric_val_prev_yr
  from your_table;
```

One more approach (cross join with stack metric_nm to multiply rows x number of metric_nm values ), this CROSS JOIN will be executed as map-join:

```
--configuration
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set hive.mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false;
set mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=36;
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=true; --this enables map-join

select dept_id, s.metric_nm,  

           case s.metric_nm when 'emp_cnt'   then emp_cnt 
                            when 'sales_cnt' then sales_cnt 
                            --add more cases
            end as metric_val, 

           case s.metric_nm when 'emp_cnt'   then emp_cnt_prev_yr 
                            when 'sales_cnt' then sales_cnt_prev_yr 
                            --add more cases
            end as metric_val_prev_yr

      from your_table 
           cross join 
           (select stack (2, --number of values, add more 
                          'sales_cnt', 
                          'emp_cnt'
                          --add more values
                         ) as metric_nm
           )s
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. You solution works well but if we have multiple metrics then below solution would be optimal I believe.  SELECT dept_id,metric_nm, SUBSTR(metrics,1,locate('#',metrics,1)-1) as metric_val, SUBSTR(metrics,locate('#',metrics,1)+1) as metric_val_prev_yr from (select dept_id, MAP('emp_cnt', CONCAT(emp_cnt,'#',emp_cnt_prev_yr),'sales_cnt', CONCAT(sales_cnt,'#',sales_cnt_prev_yr)) as metrc from <table>) a LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(metric) ext AS metric_nm, metrics;

Comment: @UmaMaheshKambala You can check it. Bui in my opinion cheaper way exists to multiply rows. Use cross join with (select stack (2, 'sales_cnt', 'emp_cnt')  )s